# How to find and edit manually the top bar option on a child theme (Wordpress)

Tags: html, css, wordpress

Any advise on how I can add an html code on (not a floating plugin) to the top bar of my website. When I enable the top bar option of my child theme, it comes with a built-in menu selection option, and I don't know where to look it for, on the WordPress file editor, so I can add an HTML code with a simple html phone link aligned to the center

Where should I look for the actual place which if I insert the phone text manually, It will show it, when I enable the top bar

this is the [website](http://ampmdoorservices.ca/)

Theme

Comment: This is a very vague question, please be more descriptive.

Comment: You can search all files of Wordpress for known content of the top bar. There, in this file, you can add the text. In `PHP`.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not within the bounds of discussion as described in the help center.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the theme your are using is following proper hierarchy, the #1 spot to look for when trying to make this kind of a change would be inside your header.php file, within your theme.

If the goal is to simply have a phone number at the very top of your website, and have it centered, you can add the following code to your header.php (IMMEDIATELY after your  tag is opened, like so:

```
<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
<div style="text-align:center;font-size:16px;">(555) - 555 - 5555</div>
```

Change the font-size with whatever size you want, and the phone number with the phone number you'd like in the top bar. This has been tested and it should work.